# Find a linear operator given the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

"Find a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ so that the kernel is generated by $(1,2,-1)$ and $(1,-1,0)$."

It's been a while since I've worked with linear algebra, but from memory I know that the kernel is a set of vectors that makes $T(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$. I started with a simple guess,
$$T(x,y,z)=(ax+by+cz,~ax+by+cz,~ax+by+cz)$$
and plugged in the given vectors, which gives the system
$$\begin{cases}a+2b-c=0\\a-b=0\end{cases}$$
and one solution set would be $a=b=1,~c=3$. Would this be a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Perhaps you want $a(1,2,-1)+b(1,-1,0)=(0,0,0)$.. Also since the kernel has dimension 2 you should expect the range to be a line through the origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that works. Strictly speaking your logic has been "if the kernel is generated by [...], then [...], and then $a = b = 1$, $c = 3$", so you want to make sure that it works the other way: that if $a = b = 1$ and $c = 3$, then the kernel is generated by those two vectors. Now you have essentially done this implicitly the way you found $a$, $b$, and $c$, but now that you've found the values, you could also do it explicitly: let $T$ be given by $T(x,y,z) = (x+y+3z) \cdot (1,1,1)$ and show that the kernel of $T$ is generated by the desired two vectors.

Just to make precise why you should be a bit cautious: another fine solution to that system would have been $a = b = c = 0$, but if you had used that to define $T$, the kernel would *not* be generated by those two vectors.